# Use router as external high powered Wi-Fi adapter

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, openwrt

I need a powerful external Wi-Fi adapter for a couple of days.
I heard that some types of router support this mode, allowing me to connect the router to my notebook and just use it as an external Wi-Fi interface.

Is it possible to connect a router as an external Wi-Fi adapter?

How can I determine it?

---

**Updated:**
My purpose is to set the router to monitor mode and check networks around through my notebook to provide better configuration for my network (power, channels, etc).
My internal notebook Wi-Fi adapter is too weak for this purpose.

---

Should I use special drivers for that?
If yes, can someone describe, step-by-step, how to do it?

p.s.

I want to use **ASUS RT-N56U** (with [**Linux**-based firmware and root access to CLI](https://code.google.com/p/rt-n56u/)) as an external Wi-Fi adapter on **OS X** or **Ubuntu**.

If someone have info about support this feature of [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) firmware - it also be helpful.

Comment: After seeing your update: this idea is kind of backwards. Why not use the portability of your laptop or mobile phone, and some software like wifi Analyzer, wi-spy, or inSSIDer? This way you can just move around the perimeter of the network and grab all the signals.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to perform a monitor mode capture then you're going to need to use a direct attach WiFi device, something like a USB WiFi dongle. OS X by default does offer the ability to put the built-in Airport card into monitor mode, but if the signal is not strong enough, and you can't relocate to a better vantage point, then an external USB device with an attachable high-gain antenna is the only option.

Most USB devices don't have the necessary driver's for OS X to toggle monitor mode on, so you'll be better off using some form of *nix (aka, Debian, Kali, Ubuntu) where you can use open source drivers to get monitor mode going wit the USB device -- virtualization works great for this (https://www.virtualbox.org). Most of the newer kernel's work with almost every major card out there, but you're now diving into a new world when it comes to monitor mode captures. Check out this page to get started: http://www.aircrack-ng.org